# Solving $|2x-5| + |7-2x| =2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, absolute-value

$$|2x-5| + |7-2x| =2 $$

I approached this problem by making cases for the equation about the critical points i.e. $x=2.5$ and $x=3.5$ :-

- *1st* case, where $x\le2.5$ :-
  $$5-2x+2x-7 = 2 \Rightarrow 2\neq 2$$
  We can say that no solution exists in this range.
- *2nd* case, where $2.5<x\le3.5$ :-
  $$2x-5+2x-7 = 2 \Rightarrow x=3.5$$
  We can say that one solution exists in this range.
- *3rd* case, where $x>3.5$ :-
  $$2x-5+7-2x = 2 \Rightarrow 2=2$$
  We can say that infinite solutions exist in this case.

So, as per above calculations, what I can conclude that for all $x\geq2.5 $ solution exists.

But the solution provided in the book says that $|2x-5| + |7-2x| =2 $ will only be valid when $2.5 \leq x \leq 3.5$.

> Can someone please help me out on how to decide the solutions and solution ranges for these type of questions?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In your $1$st case, i.e., with $x \le 2.5$, and your $2$nd case, i.e., with $2.5 \lt x \le 3.5$, then $| 7 - 2x | = 7 - 2x$, not $2x  - 7$ as you stated. Also, in your $3$rd case, i.e., with $x \gt 3.5$, then $| 7 - 2x | = 2x - 7$, not $7 - 2x$ as you stated. In other words, you have those results for $| 7 - 2x |$ mixed around.

Comment: MathJax tip: If you want text in your mathematical expressions, try using the `\text{}` command. For example, `$$\{x^ay^b : \text{$a$ is odd and $b$ is even}\}.$$` produces:$$\{x^ay^b : \text{$a$ is odd and $b$ is even}\}.$$

Comment: @TheoBendit : noted and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short cut way: let $y=2x$, what are the values that $y$ can take such that the distance from $5$ and the distance from $7$ are exactly $2$. If $y$ is less than $5$, then the distance from $7$ is beyond $2$. SImilarly if $y$ is more than $7$, then the distance from $5$ is beyond $2$. We can easily check that any values of  $y$ between $5$ and $7$ satisfies the condition and hence $x$ is in between $2.5$ and $3.5$.

---

Now, as a practice, let's work it out.

- If $x \le 2.5$, then $|2x-5|=5-2x$, $|7-2x|=7-2x$.

Hence $$5-2x+7-2x=2$$
$$10=4x$$

and hence the only solution is $x=2.5$.

- If $2.5 < x <3.5$, then $|2x-5|=2x-5$ and $|7-2x|=7-2x$.

$$2x-5+7-2x=2$$

which is always true.

- If $x \ge 3.5$, $|2x-5|=2x-5$ and $|7-2x|=2x-7$

$$4x-12=2$$

$$2x=7$$ the only solution is $3.5$.

Hence taking union: $\{2.5\} \cup (2.5, 3.5) \cup \{3.5\}=[2.5,3.5]$ is the desired result.

Comment: What if $x \leq 2.5$ then $$10=4x$$ is a valid solution in this case, right? I am getting confused in these things only like in which case I need to take $\leq$. Can you please clarify me on this? And the $2nd$ case now be $2.5 \lt x \le 3.5$ and in this case too $$2x-5+7-2x=2$$ which is always true.

Comment: Sure, if you consider $x \le 2.5$, you will find that $x=2.5$ is a solution. Just that since I have eyeballed the solution, I intentionally group the set of solution in one case.

Comment: Then is it right to say that there the solution range will depend on how one has taken the inequality condition while making the cases?

Comment: You have the freedom to partition the cases, but in the end when you take the union of all the solutions, you should get a consistent result.

Comment: OK..i'll try this problem one more time from my side taking different partitioning of the cases unlike you have taken and will let you know if I have any confusion. Thanks for such a quick response !

Comment: Hi ! I tried solving this time taking cases as $x \leq 2.5$ , $2.5 \lt x \lt 3.5$ and $x \geq 3.5$ then I can see that all the three ranges are valid solution ranges. Can you please tell me how to take the union in this case to approach to the solution? Maybe you can modify your answer for what I have asked in my comment for clear understanding. Thanks!

Comment: edited my answer according to the cases that you requested.

Comment: thanks! I got it...now I think I got a better understanding at this...thanks for all your help...

Answer (score 1):

WLOG for real $x,$

$$|2x-5|=2\sin^2t,|7-2x|=2\cos^2t$$

$$(2x-5)^2-(7-2x)^2=4(\cos^2t-\sin^2t)$$

$$\implies2x=6-\cos2t\implies-1\le2x-6\le1\iff 5\le2x\le7$$

In that case $|2x-5|=+(2x-5)$ and $|7-2x|=+(7-2x)$

Answer (score 1):

A quite quick way to solve this inequality is using the triangle inequality:

$$|2x-5| + |7-2x|\geq |2x-5+7-2x| = 2$$

The triangle inequality $|a| + |b| \geq |a+b|$ turns in an equality $|a|+|b| =|a+b|$ if and only if $ab=|ab|$. (Just square $|a| + |b| \geq |a+b|$ and rearrange).

Hence, you only need to find those $x$ for which $2x-5$ and $7-2x$ have the same sign:

Case $\geq 0$:

$2x-5 \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow x\geq \frac 52$.

$7-2x \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow x\leq \frac 72$.

So, this gives the solution $\boxed{x\in \left[\frac 52,\frac72\right]}$.

Case $\leq 0$:

$2x-5 \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow x\leq \frac 52$.

$7-2x \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow x\geq \frac 72$.

Hence, no further solution.

Comment: Can you please provide any relevant document or video link to understand this triangle inequality concept?

Comment: See for example here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInequality.html

This is a well known standard inequality which is often very helpful when dealing with equations or inequalities containing absolute values.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have the info about $7-2x$ completely backwards.  I $x \le 3.5$ then $7-2x \ge 0$ and $|7-2x| = 7-2x$.

And if $x >3.5$ then $7-2x < 0$ and $|7-2x| = 2x - 7$.

So case 1: $x <2.5$ then $|2x - 5|+|7-2x| = (5-2x)+(7-2x) = 2$ and $12-4x = 2$ and $x =2.5$ but $x < 2.5$ so that isn't a solution.

Case 2: $2.5 \le x \le 3.5$ and $|2x-5|+|7-2x|=(2x-5)+(7-2x)= 2$ and $2=2$ has infinite solutions.

Case 3: $x > 3.5$ then $|2x-5|-|7-2x| = (5-2x) -(2x-7)= 12 - 4x = 2$ so $x=-2.5$ but $x > 3.5$ so that isn't a solution.

....

Note $|7-2x| = |2x-7|$ so the critical points don't have to mean $x < critical\implies (central stuff) < 0$ and $x > critical \implies (central stuff) > 0$.

It could be the *exact* opposite.  One key thing to note $2x -7$ has a positive coefficient so it has $<> critical \implies <> 0$.  But a *negative* coefficient would imply $<> critical \implies >< 0$.